# How to set up multiple passwords for one wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, passwords, user

I want to set up a WiFi network, like a digital cafe where people can pay to use the internet for 24 hours.

I would need a system of one password per user so one password wouldn't work for 20 people. I'd also need a way for them to pay with PayPal before accessing the internet. Once they paid, they would be given a unique password that would work for 24 hours.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

There are a many (most of them, open source) projects out there that allow you to install alternate firmware on your router to allow you to do things like this.

Some popular ones are [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), [PFSense](http://pfsense.org/), [OpenWrt](http://wiki.openwrt.org/start):

You can use something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/); their captive portal wiki section via PayPal is [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal).

Or you can use [PFSense](http://pfsense.org/); their implementation is using vouchers - they pay you (not via PayPal), and you give them a one-time access code. See [here](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal) for more info on that.

You will probably need to buy a compatible router depending on the firmware you choose. For more captive portal options, see the Wikipedia link I mentioned on the first line.

Note: None of these options can let you 'set up multiple passwords for one wireless network' - but they allow you to basically achieve the same thing - ask people to pay to access internet.